# Prove or Disprove: There are bounded, countable subsets of R^2 that have positive area.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Recall that a bounded set S in $R^2$ has area iff the inner area of S equals the outer area of S (and consequently the area of S equals said inner/outer area).

My instinct tells me the statement is false, reasoning that a countable subset would have to be a set of disconnected points (?) and so the inner area would always equal zero, and thus the area itself would either be zero (if the outer area also happened to be zero) or would not exist at all (if the outer area was strictly greater than zero).

Thoughts?

Comment: What is inner area and outer area? Are you familiar with Lebesgue measure? In that case, any countable set, bounded or not, has zero measure (or area).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Lebesque measure but I appreciate your response; it at least confirms that my instinct was right to an extent. I don't know how to succinctly explain the inner and outer area, but basically the inner area is the supremum of lower sums, where the lower sum is a summation of subrectangles that are contained with the set; and the outer area is similarly the infimum of upper sums, where the upper sum is a summation of subrectangles that are both contained within the set and also those that intersect the boundary of the set (but may not be fully contained within the set).

Comment: You should put the question in the body of your question rather than partly in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that the area of a part of a set is always at most the area of the set, one can proceed as follows. Assume that $S=\{s_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ and consider $A_\epsilon$ the union of the balls $B(s_n,\epsilon/n)$. Since the area of $B(s_n,\epsilon/n)$ is $\pi\epsilon^2/n^{2}$, the area of $A_\epsilon$ is at most
$$
\sum_n\pi\epsilon^2/n^{2}=\pi^3\epsilon^2/6\lt6\epsilon^2.
$$
Finally, since $S\subseteq A_\epsilon$, the area of $S$ is at most $6\epsilon^2$, for every positive $\epsilon$, hence the area of $S$ is zero.

This only uses that $S$ is countable, not that $S$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

> guest314159265: I don't know how to succinctly explain the inner and outer area, but
>   basically the inner area is the supremum of lower sums, where the
>   lower sum is a summation of subrectangles that are contained with the
>   set; and the outer area is similarly the infimum of upper sums, where
>   the upper sum is a summation of subrectangles that are both contained
>   within the set and also those that intersect the boundary of the set
>   (but may not be fully contained within the set).

It is not very rigorous but imagine you have a countable set $S \subset \mathbb R^2$ containing a rectangle $R$ with nonempty interior, i.e. $int(R)\neq \emptyset$. Then the set $R$ must be countable because it is a subset of a countable set. Let $x \in int(T)$, w.l.o.g. $x \neq 0$, then by definition of the interior there must be some $\epsilon> 0$ such that the ball centered in $x$ and of radius epsilon is contained in $R$, that is $B(x, \epsilon)\subset R$.

Now let $\psi:[0,1] \to \mathbb R^2:t \mapsto (1+\frac{\epsilon}{2} t)x$, it is clear that $Im(\psi) \subset R$ and $\psi$ is an injective map since we supposed $x \neq 0$. But then $\phi:[0,1] \to Im(\psi):t \mapsto \psi(t)$ is a bijection, and thus $[0,1]$ must be countable since $Im(\phi)$ is subset of a countable set. This is a contradiction.

This shows that with the definition of area you gave, a countable set can only have a zero inner area.